# Toggle audio on click of element?

Tags: jquery, audio, click, toggle

How do I toggle audio on click of a single element?

Please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/zy2jD/1/

```
$("#one").toggle(function () {
$('#sound-1').get(0).play();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to play/pause the song :
http://jsfiddle.net/RGJCf/36/

HTML :

```
<div id="one" class="bar1">
    <i class="play">I tried to tell you</i>
    <i class="stop">I tried to tell you</i>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.stop{
    display:none;
}
```

JS :

```
$("#one").click(function () {
    if ($('#sound-1').get(0).paused == false) {
        $('#sound-1').get(0).pause();
        alert('music paused');
    } else {
        $('#sound-1').get(0).play();
        alert('music playing');
    }
    $('i').toggle();
});
```